# How to format a string longer than 99 characters in Lua

Tags: lua, console

I am formatting strings to be printed to the console and trying to format for the terminal size. However, Lua appears to not allow any type of formatting longer than 99 characters. ([source](https://github.com/lua/lua/blob/master/lstrlib.c#L975))

In a case where the terminal is greater than 100 columns wide, how else can I pad a string to use the full line? Or print something right-aligned? I know I can do the math and pad spaces with a loop, but that feels inefficient. Is there something else I'm missing? Maybe some terminal control characters?

**Update**: I linked the wrong place in the source. [This](https://github.com/lua/lua/blob/master/lstrlib.c#L1081) appears to be the function that I'm getting hung up on. It allows only 2 digits to specify the field size, as commented on line 1087.

An example of what I'm trying to do:

Every X iteration of an operation, I print a line with a format like so:

```
"\rDone: %d, Left %d, Current: %s"
```

This clears the line every time to keep a status update with out spamming the console with lines.

*The Problem* with this is when the string `/long-path/to/file-name` is printed as the `%s` argument and the next iteration prints `/path/to/file`, part of the previous line is left as it's not overwritten by the shorter line. Using format to pad the line out to the full width of the console prevents these "left over" characters.

Comment: `MAX_ITEM` is about the lengths of the individual items consumed during formatting. It's not about the actual size of the resulting string. Also `MAX_ITEM` is 120 characters, as clearly indicated in that link, not 99.

Comment: It's possible I didn't link to the right spot in the Lua source, my understanding of C is not very good; and admittedly my time spent reading this source was not much. However, testing actual Lua code shows that the format "%99s" works, while "%100s" fails with error "(width or precision too long)".

Comment: Right, but `"%s"` works just fine regardless of how many characters are in the given string. So why would you explicitly limit the number of characters?

Comment: Ah, my title might be misleading. I'm not talking about formatting a string longer than 99 characters but applying a format that has a field longer than 99 characters. The "why" is a terminal line that is longer than 99 characters. Say I want to give a few stats and then put a xx% done indicator on the right right of the line. In other languages I've done this by formatting the string with the full width of the terminal. It's more about padding than limiting.

Comment: [Here](https://www.lua.org/source/5.3/lstrlib.c.html#scanformat) is the function in lstrlib.c where the field width is limited to a two-digit number. (Linking to lua.org may be more durable.)

Answer (score 2):

You could try printing some [ANSI Escape Codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code). See the "cursor position" codes.

Since you can't write the control codes directly into the string, you'll have to use [string.char](http://lua-users.org/wiki/StringLibraryTutorial) to generate a string containing the control codes.

Another alternative option is to pre-generate padding strings of each length required and reference them later:

```
padding = {}
padding[1] = " "
for i = 2,MAX_PAD do
  padding[i] = padding[i-1].." "
end
-- now padding[i] is a string of i spaces.
```

concatenate the padding string with the rest of your format string before passing to `string.format`.

Comment: I specifically don't want to concat strings in a loop, but the cursor position control codes do allow me to do math to right-align output.

Answer (score 1):

> Using format to pad the line out to the full width of the console prevents these "left over" characters.

So would this:

```
local str = string.format("\rDone: %d, Left %d, Current: %s", ...)
if(#str > line_length) then
  str = str .. string.rep(" ", line_length - #str)
end
```

Comment: Not the way I'm going to go with it, but I hadn't even thought of using string.rep, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

The bulk of my problem is solved with the `ESC[2K` control character. Instead of trying to cover up the previous line with spaces, that control code deletes the entire line. Here is a good looking reference for VT100 control codes: http://www.termsys.demon.co.uk/vtansi.htm